# Datetime in SQL Server and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have this simple query

```
insert into my_table(date) values(getdate())
```

The result is `2017-01-05 12:41:37.273`.

I want when I do

```
select * 
from my_table
```

from my Windows Forms application to set the label1.text = 5 Thu 12:41

```
2017-01-05 12:41:37.273 ----> 5 Thu 12:41
```

How can I achieve that with C# code ?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, which includes `SqlReader`, `DataSet`, Entity Framework and LINQ2SQL. You have to narrow down the options and try your solution first, before this question can be answered in any useful way.

Comment: You can also use string formatting to format the datetime. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you read the data from SQL Server into your C# application I'm pretty sure, that a column of sql type `DATETIME` will be mapped to a C# type `DateTime`.

What you need is the textual format of this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(d.ToString("d ddd HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse string to DateTime and wrtie your own format.

```
  DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-05 12:41:37");
  string formatedDateTime = myDateTime.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Comment: It would be better if you used the format required in the sample code, e.g. `"dd ddd HH:mm"`

Comment: Thank u so much :)

Answer (score 0):

From SQL you can you the below format to get your expected result:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(D, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + 
       LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), 3) + ' ' + 
       LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108), 5)

-- Output: 5 Thu 05:22
```

Comment: OP mentioned that he wants to achieve it via C# code.

Comment: It is a bad idea, to call data from a database not in the appropriate type. This display-format is the very last step and shoudl be done on the presentation layer. The value `5 Thu 12:41` would eveb be of no meaning without a year...

Comment: :) Thank u .. Works fine